# Custom Horizontal StackView on the Android Platform

Tags: android, android-library, coverflow

I'm trying to design a UI on the Android Platform (Version 4.0) which would be similar to the Cover Flow design of the Apple App Store as seen from the iPad. (Please view the attached screenshot).

![CoverFlowA][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pF2EC.png

The nearest Android component to this, which I found is the StackView.

QUESTIONS:
1. Is this the Correct Android component? If not, then which one to use?

1. Is it possible to extend the StackView to mimic this UI?
2. Is there any API/Library available for this on the Android platform?

Comment: Check out this link: http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/ It is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I spent some time on it and later saw that the code is using the Gallery Class of Android. Since this Gallery has now been deprecated so, is there some other way to implement this?