# Horizontal swiping in stackview

Tags: java, android, stackview

I am in an app which requires stackview. But I have to implement horizontal swiping to switch between stackview items and UI looks as that of as normal one. Please help me to make it.

I have already checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956086/custom-horizontal-stackview-on-the-android-platform).

But in it UI is just a cover flow. I want to make the UI look same as stackview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iam create a custom stack-view

```
  public class custom_stackview extends StackView{

    float x1, x2, y1, y2, dx, dy;
    public custom_stackview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public custom_stackview(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onTouchEvent(event);

        switch(event.getAction()) {
            case(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
                x1 = event.getX();
                y1 = event.getY();
                break;
           case(MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE):
           case(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) :{
            x2 = event.getX();
            y2 = event.getY();
            dx = x2 - x1;
            dy = y2 - y1;

            // Use dx and dy to determine the direction
            if (Math.abs(dx) > Math.abs(dy)) {
                if (dx > 0) {// direction = "right";
                    showNext();
                } else {

                    showPrevious();


                }

            }
            }
         // Log.v("hiiiiiiiiiii", direction+re);
        }
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stubLog.v("hiiiiiiiiiii","touched");
        Log.v("hiiiiiiiiiii","toucheddddddddd");
        //boolean re =false;


        return false;
    }

}
```

use as

```
 <package_name.custom_stackview
        android:id="@+id/stackview"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:loopViews="true"
        />
```

Comment: +1 for almost complete solution - I needed to fix the following code in order for it the perform good - remove `case(MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE):` and add `default: break;`, otherwise it keeps moving the views while moving\swiping.

Answer (score 0):

Recently came across a great little hack for this.
In your layout XML use:

```
<StackView
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:rotation = "-90" />
```

Then within the item's XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:rotation = "90" />
```

You can play with the numbers to change the direction however you need.